# $R$ a ring and $M$ a left $R$ module, define ring morphisms $\phi: R \to End_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$ and $\phi': End_{\mathbb{Z}}(M) \to R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a ring and  let $M$ a left $R$ module. I want to show we can define ring morphisms $\phi: R \to End_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$ and $\phi': End_{\mathbb{Z}}(M) \to R$. For $\phi: R \to End_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$, I defined $\phi(r):= f$ for every $r \in R$ where $f: M \to M$ is defined as $f(m):= rm$ for every $m \in M$. It is clear that $f$ is well defined and that $\phi$ is also well defined and its a ring morphism. On the other hand, Im run out of ideas to properly define  a ring morphism $\phi': End_{\mathbb{Z}}(M) \to R$. I mean, if we have $f \in End_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$, how can we have assign $f$ and  element $r \in R$?

Comment: Try $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $M = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Out of curiousity [maybe because I haven't give this much of a thought], what makes the OP believe the "universal" existence of ring morphism $\operatorname{End}_{\Bbb Z}M \to R$ provided that $M$ is a left $R$-module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a general solution to your question. However, what you can always do is simply define a ring morphism
$$
\phi' : \text{End}_\mathbb{Z}(M) \to R, \quad f \mapsto 0_R.
$$
This solves your problem, even though it is quite boring.

Here's a counterexample: Building on Jake Levinson's comment: Let $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $M = \mathbb{Z}/4$. Since $\text{End}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}/4) \cong \mathbb{Z}/4$, we can write $\text{End}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}/4) = \{ f_0,f_1,f_2,f_4 \}$, where $f_0(\overline{x}) = \overline{0}$ for all $\overline{x} \in \mathbb{Z}/4$ and $f_1 = \text{id}_{\mathbb{Z}/4}$. The morphisms $f_2$ and $f_3$ are given by
$$
f_2 = \left(\begin{matrix}
  \overline{0} & \overline{1} & \overline{2} & \overline{3} \\
  \overline{0} & \overline{3} & \overline{2} & \overline{1}
\end{matrix}\right),\quad
f_3 = \left(\begin{matrix}
  \overline{0} & \overline{1} & \overline{2} & \overline{3} \\
  \overline{0} & \overline{2} & \overline{0} & \overline{2}
\end{matrix}\right).
$$
Then, the canonical choice for $\phi'$ would be to define
$$
\phi' : \text{End}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}/4) \to \mathbb{Z},\quad f_k \mapsto k,
$$
for $k \in \{0,1,2,3\}$. However, this is not a morphism, since $(f_1+f_3)(\overline{1}) = \overline{3}$, but $(f_{1+3})(\overline{1}) = f_4(\overline{1}) = f_0(\overline{1})$, since $4=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/4$. Therefore, we have $f_k+f_\ell \neq f_{k+\ell}$ for $k,\ell \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ and hence $\phi'$ is not a ring morphism.